# selecting multiple columns and looping through the selected rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I want to be able to select multiple columns and loop through the retrieved rows and store the selected fields in a string.

Something like select a.firstname, a.lastname from customer where a.id = '123' and loop through the retireved rows and have them write to a string like

```
FirstName = John; LastName = Doe
FirstName = Steve; LastName = Smith
```

I have linq statement as

```
IList<string> strgradeandbatch = new List<string>();
strgradeandbatch = context.GradeAndBatches
                         .Where(T => T.RequestGuid == request.ItemGuid)
                         .Select(T => new{T.GradeName, T.Batch}).ToList();
```

Obviously this is wrong, and not sure how to do it.Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost correct. Just remove `IList<string> strgradeandbatch = new List<string>()` and use anonymous type `var strgradeandbatch`.

```
string GradeName, Batch;
var strgradeandbatch = context.GradeAndBatches
                         .Where(T => T.RequestGuid == request.ItemGuid)
                         .Select(T => new{T.GradeName, T.Batch}).ToList();
foreach(var item in strgradeandbatch)
{
   GradeName = item.GradeName;
   Batch = item.Batch;
}
```

*(Note:If you use anonymous type, you can't return this value from the method)*

Comment: This just overwrites `GradeName` and `Batch` a number of times. Not very useful.

Comment: Yes, have to use the value before next loop.

Answer (score 1):

The Select method projects the query results into a list of an anonymous type objects, so it can be used with a list for strings.

One solution is to create a new class

```
public class Grade

{
   public string GradeName {get; set;}
   public string Batch {get; set;}
}
```

Which is going to be used with the Select method

```
var strgradeandbatch = context.GradeAndBatches
                         .Where(T => T.RequestGuid == request.ItemGuid)
                         .Select(T => new Grade
                              { 
                                GradeName = T.GradeName, 
                                Batch = T.Batch
                             }).ToList();
```